# Array counting by 5's and 3's then adding the arrays

Tags: java

I have 3 arrays iX, iY, and iZ with each holding 20 integers.

iX goes up by 5, iY goes up by 3, and iZ is the sum of both.

```
for (int i=5; i <=iX.length; i+=5)
{
    iX[i] = i;
    System.out.print (i + "\n");
}

for (int j=3; j <iY.length; j+=3)
{
    iY[j] = j;
}
for (int k=0; k < iZ.length; k++)
{
    iZ[k] = iX[k]+iY[k];
}
```

When I run it I get:
 "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 20
    at Quiz10RTN.main(Quiz10RTN.java:61)"

Line 61 is : iX[i] = i;

I can't seem to get it to even print out 20 numbers, because it seems to be treating my limit of 20 integers as a range to stop at. Any help would be great, Thanks.

Comment: Arrays are indexed from zero. In other words, 0 to array.length - 1 are valid indices. You are trying to access index 20 (the 21st index) in an array of size 20.

Answer (score 3):

Issue is here

```
for (int i=5; i <=iX.length; i+=5)
                 ^
```

There is no index match with `iX.length` in your array.

index of array start with `0`, So if size of array is `n`, then you only have indexes from `0` to `n-1`.

You can use following to avoid the exception. But you need to think some other way to archive your goal.

```
for (int i=5; i <iX.length; i+=5)
```

Edit: for your comment `I was trying to print out "5, 10, 15, 20, 25...etc"`

You can try something like following

```
for (int i=0; i <iX.length; i++) {
   iX[i]=(i+1)*5; // now your array become 5,10,15,...      
}
```

Comment: I'm still only getting 3 as opposed to 20 integers printing out, "5, 10, and 15"

Comment: What else you expect? here is what your have wrote. `iX[i] = i;
          System.out.print (i + "\n");`

Comment: I was trying to print out "5, 10, 15, 20, 25...etc"

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing your array indices with the values you are storing in the arrays.

So, for example, if you want your iX array to contain the 20 integers 5, 10, 15,...100, your first loop should look like:

```js
      for (int i=0; i < iX.length; ++i)
      {
          iX[i] = (i + 1) * 5;
          System.out.print (iX[i] + "\n");
      }
```

Comment: FYI:  Code snippets only really apply to questions that are HTML/Javascript based.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using the array indexes properly (they must be incremental). You might also use [`Arrays.toString(int[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int[]%29) to print your arrays. I believe you wanted something like

```
int[] iX = new int[20];
int[] iY = new int[20];
int[] iZ = new int[20];
int valfive = 5; // <-- our five increments.
int valthree = 3; // <-- the three increments.
for (int i = 0; i < iX.length; i++) {
    iX[i] = valfive;
    iY[i] = valthree;
    iZ[i] = valfive + valthree;
    valfive += 5; // <-- add 5
    valthree += 3; // <-- add 3
}
System.out.println("Multiples of five: " + Arrays.toString(iX));
System.out.println("Multiples of three: " + Arrays.toString(iY));
System.out.println("Sums of fives and threes: " + Arrays.toString(iZ));
```

Output is (formatted for SO)

```
Multiples of five: [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 
        75, 80, 85, 90, 95, 100]
Multiples of three: [3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39, 42, 
        45, 48, 51, 54, 57, 60]
Sums of fives and threes: [8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56, 64, 72, 80, 88, 96, 
        104, 112, 120, 128, 136, 144, 152, 160]
```

Comment: @ElliotFrisch Instead of printing it out horizontally, is there a way I could display all 3 arrays vertically? e.g. iX  iY  IZ with the numbers going down under the corresponding array?

Comment: @ph0bolus Yes, but I think you'll find it easiest to use three loops (one to print each array). Like `for (int i : iX) { System.out.println(i); }` and so on...